# Which AuthorizationFilterAttribute method should I override?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to create my custom authorization filter. I see that in System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute there are two similar methods IsAuthorized and OnAuthorization. Which one should I override and why?

Comment: It would help if you would tell us why you want to create your own filter.  Quite often, people assume that they have to do this, when they usually don't.

Comment: Incoming request has a RSA signature header that I need to validate. If you think that there is a better solution, I would be happy to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override **IsAuthorized**, which *"Determines whether access for this particular request is authorized."*